# JQuery - How to check if a scrollbar is at the bottom for all browsers

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

How do you check in JQuery if an element has his scrollbar at the bottom? The  html structure is something like this

```
<div class="container">
 <ol class="list">
     <li class="item">Item 1</li>
     ....
 </ol>
</div>
```

.container is the one that gets a scrollbar if the items under ol.list goes over the defined height.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check whether the container's scrollTop() jQuery value is equal to the domelement's scrollHeight minus the container's height. Then the scrollbar is at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/KxZDK/2/

EDIT: since in IE7, scrollHeight would actually be smaller than the height rather than be equal to the height if the contents would be smaller, so use larger than equal to make the result always be true even if there is no scrollbar.

I also updated the fiddle link.

Comment: In the case of an overflow when the container's overflow is set to auto, scroll or hidden, the scrollHeight will be the height that would be required so that a scrollbar wouldn't appear in case of overflow: auto.
Check my updated link with the height and scrollHeight values alerted out.
http://jsfiddle.net/KxZDK/1/

EDIT: ah, it seems the user who commented before me removed his comment. I'll keep this comment of mine though.

Comment: I am sorry, my comment was complete bogus. I mixed up several jsfiddle instances... Be aware that according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight the scrollHeight property is not supported in IE < 8

Comment: I tried it in jsfiddle, and it seems that the only difference in IE7 is that scrollHeight can show a value that is smaller than the height. I amended my answer to mention it. Other than that it works fine, even when zooming (by googling I read some people say it works weird when the page is zoomed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function mentioned below to get the height of the container and use this height to compare against the defined height to know if there are scrollbar or not.

```
$('.list').height()
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. What I am looking for is to check if the scrollbar is at the bottom, not to check if there is a scrollbar visible.